# Appending button to a new line

Tags: jquery

I need to append a button with a Bootstrap class with the same line.

I have this append line that add data to table after successful insertion into server:

```
$("#id_of_my_tr").before("<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+last_n+"</td><td>"+addr+"</td><td>"+btn+"</td></tr>");
```

And it works properly. Now I need to append a button to the same line that have a bootstrap class.

I tried this script:

```
var btn = $('<button type="Button" id="del" name="del" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>');
```

And then I add it in the append before script line:

```
$("#before_tr").before("<tr><td>"+emp+"</td><td>"+pos+"</td><td>"+sal+"</td><td>"+btn+"</td></tr>");
```

The result is, when a new line added, instead of a button, I get a text that said:

> [object Object].

**UPDATE**

I tried to add the button HTML as:

```
$("#before_tr").before("<tr><td>"+emp+"</td><td>"+pos+"</td><td>"+sal+"</td><td><button type="Button" id="del" name="del" class="btn btn-danger">"Delete"</button></td></tr>");
```

But I've got an empty cell

Comment: You're appending an object to a string, hence it's coerced and you see `[object Object]`. Can you not just add the button HTML string to the `before()` call?

Comment: I tried it and I got an empty cell with no button. See my edit in just 1 min

Comment: Replace `<button type="Button" id="del" name="del" class="btn btn-danger">"Delete"</button>` to `<button type='Button' id='del' name='del' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your attempt to add the HTML is with your quoting. You used the same type of quotes around the string as you used around the attributes in the string, so the attribute quotes were ending the string. Use single quotes around the string so they don't conflict with the double quotes around the attributes.

```
$("#before_tr").before("<tr><td>"+emp+"</td><td>"+pos+"</td><td>"+sal+'</td><td><button type="Button" id="del" name="del" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this hack

```
var btn = '<button type="Button" id="del" name="del" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>';
$("#before_tr").before("<tr><td>"+emp+"</td><td>"+pos+"</td><td>"+sal+"</td><td>"+btn+"</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of problems you can create detached DOM elements, and work with them as pure elements. Then you can attach them to the page DOM.

I.e. something like this:

```
var $tr = $('<tr>');
var $td1 = $('<td>').html(name);
var $td2 = $('<td>').html(last_name);
var $td2 = $('<td>').html(addr);
var $td3 = $('<td>');
var $btn = $('<button>').attr('type','button').attr('id','del')
   .attr('name','del').addClass('btn btn-danger').html('Delete');
$td3.append($btn);
$tr.append($td1).append($td2).append($td3);
```

And finally you can attach the button to the page's DOM, using whichever function you want, like '.before'.

I've done it extremely verbose. You can always find your own balance of readability/verbosity. This allows to handle complex HTML in a very safe way, avoiding lots of mistakes.